# How to make domain alias as primary domain in google apps

Tags: google-api, google-apps

How do i make an alias of my google apps primary domain as my primary domain?

For example my primary domain is a.com and I have an alias for a.com as alias.com, how can i make alias.com as the primary domain?

Answer (score 1):

[Changing the customer's primary domain](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers/patch) only supports usage of secondary domains as the new primary domain. Domain aliases cannot be used.

You'll need to remove the domain alias from the account and then re-add the domain as a secondary domain before you can make it the primary.